# Issue with git blame -M -C when trying to move code

Tags: git

git is supposed to index content instead of files
Thanks to this, when you move a piece of code from one file to another, with

```
git blame -M -C <destination file>
```

you can see the original blame from the source file, when the file is committed

My issue is that it doesn't works every time for me, and I don't understand why !
From the first file, I select a piece of code, then cut it (Ctrl+X) and copy it to the destination file (Ctrl+V)
Then I save both file, and commit them in the same commit
When I do a 'git blame -M -C', no matter how many '-C' I add, most of the time (**but not every time**) the code that I copied appear under my name and not the original writer
I tried different way to cut and paste, adding blank lines, removing somes ... suddenly it works but without real and visible reason

I probably do something wrong, but I can't see what
Can you help me ?